# For Loop Copy Command

Tags: command-line

I have a file, `FileToCopy.pbs`, that I would like to copy into multiple directories while changing a line called `xxx` in the file to the `pwd` location of the directory in which the file is to be copied.

What kind of for loop can I use to make this command?

Also, some of my directories include a `*` at the end of the directory path name.

More specifically I have a directory structure:

```
/home/path1/dir1
/home/path1/dir2
/home/path1/dir3*
/home/path1/dir4*
.
.
etc
```

and would like to copy `FileToCopy.pbs` into all directories so that I have:

```
/home/path1/dir1/FileToCopy.pbs
/home/path1/dir2/FileToCopy.pbs
/home/path1/dir3*/FileToCopy.pbs
/home/path1/dir4*/FileToCopy.pbs
```

while changing a line `xxx` in each copied file of `FileToCopy.pbs` to the directory in which it is in. For instance, the line `xxx` for the `FileToCopy.pbs` located in `/home/path1/dir1/` should be changed to `/home/path1/dir1/`

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I have figured it out.

The code is as follows:

In the directory `/home/path1/`

```
for i in *; do cp /directory/of/FileToCopy.pbs $i; cd $i; sed -i s#xxx#$(pwd)#g FileToCopy.pbs ; cd /home/path1/; done
```